# Purchasing more than one lottery ticket

Tags: halacha, hashkafah-philosophy

Disclaimer: Although the question about the permissibility of participating in a lottery has been asked and answered on this forum - my specific question has not been answered with clear sources.

Question:
Where is it mentioned that it is permissible to purchase a single lottery ticket, but not to purchase more (presumably because then you don't believe in the divine intervention and instead are leaving it up to statistics)

I am looking for a clear source that i can look up

thank you.

Comment: By how much is the chance that you'll wint the lottery increases if one buys 2 lotteries? - https://dinonline.org/2017/01/15/can-jews-buy-lottery-tickets/ -

Comment: @Shmuel i don't see how the link you attached addresses the question of only buying a single ticket

Comment: "chances of winning are very low, therefore he is just taking a chance that maybe from shomayim they will let him win." - even if you buy two tickets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Rebbe mentions [on video - 7 Tishrei 5752](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Go_SxQwSwsKlpSSkpUI-TkbWX1K82-Ou/view?usp=drivesdk) to a gentleman who asked about playing the lottery that he can play, but advises to only purchase a single ticket.